# How to figure out what is using the space on my Ubuntu LXC running qBittorrent?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage

I have a LXC in Proxmox running Ubuntu with qBittorrent on it. The boot disk looks like this from Proxmox:

[image: proxmox showing 3.26GiB disk usage]

Notice it's using 3.26GiB. A quick look at df -h confirms this:

[image: df confirming disk usage]

I have tried to track down what is using this space in multiple ways, the easiest being the command `ncdu` which shows (ignoring `/mnt/` of course as that's a samba share mount not on this drive):

[image: using ncdu command]

And `du -sh /*` has similar results:

[image: using du command]

None of this explains or can tell me where all the boot disk usage is occurring. Any ideas on how I can find out what is using the disk space? I assume it's some sort of cache from qBT but I don't know where.

Output of `du -hxd1 /`:

```
root@qbittorrent:~# du -hxd1 /
11M     /root
792M    /usr
4.0K    /srv
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /home
4.0K    /opt
16K     /lost+found
463M    /var
40K     /tmp
4.0K    /boot
4.6M    /etc
1.3G    /
```

Output of `lsof | grep -c deleted`:

```
root@qbittorrent:~# lsof | grep -c deleted
0
```

Output ls `lsblk`:

```
root@qbittorrent:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
|-sda1   8:1    0   1.8T  0 part 
`-sda9   8:9    0     8M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
|-sdb1   8:17   0   1.8T  0 part 
`-sdb9   8:25   0     8M  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
|-sdc1   8:33   0   1.8T  0 part 
`-sdc9   8:41   0     8M  0 part 
sdd      8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk 
|-sdd1   8:49   0   1.8T  0 part 
`-sdd9   8:57   0     8M  0 part 
sde      8:64   0 931.5G  0 disk 
|-sde1   8:65   0  1007K  0 part 
|-sde2   8:66   0   512M  0 part 
`-sde3   8:67   0   931G  0 part 
sdf      8:80   0   1.8T  0 disk 
|-sdf1   8:81   0   1.8T  0 part 
`-sdf9   8:89   0     8M  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code. Also add the output of `du -hxd1 /` and `lsof | grep -c deleted`

Comment: Sure, updated the post with output for those 2 commands.

Comment: You might have files being covered by something else being mounted on top. Add the output of `lsblk` as well. As an experiment, try bind-mounting `/` on some unused directory like `/media` or `/srv` and run `du` on that directory (e.g., `mount --bind / /media; du -hxd1 /media`)

Comment: isn't 3.something GB about what you would expect from qBittorrent and the libraries needed to run it? I'm a bit confused. That seems perfectly sensible!#

Comment: I added the output of `lsblk`. If you spin up a new qBT in an empty LXC it barely takes 1GB, but the point isn't about how much it is or is not using. The point is *where* is that space being consumed? Because while Proxmox says 3GB (which is accurate), within the container itself I can't seem to find where that space is being used.